# SharePoint framework yo not showing all the options

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions, yeoman-generator

I am new to SharePoint framework.  I am executing yo `@microsoft\sharepoint`. Providing all the inputs.

For the question `Which type of component to be created?` it is showing only `Webpart`. It is not showing `Extension and library`.

I have updated `node` and `yo`. I am not sure which one I am missing to get those two options made available.

[image]

yo --version
3.1.0

node -v
v13.1.0

Answer (score 4):

You have to select "SharePoint Online only (latest)" or "SharePoint 2019 onwards, including SharePoint Online" for the question `Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)?` to get option for "Extension".

---

*If the answer is helpful, please upvote and mark as accepted.*

Comment: I tried selecting SharePoint Online only (latest) as well same behavior.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint generator updated version?

Comment: I have updated with "npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g" comment. still same problem.

Comment: Try to use node version 10.x

Answer (score 2):

**Reason**:

SharePoint 2016 **does not support** SPFx extensions.

This is because SharePoint 2016 on-premises doesn't support Modern UI.

SharePoint Extensions are supported only in SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Online as of now.

**Solution**:

In order to create a SharePoint Extension choose any one of the below options for the question, **Which baseline packages do you want to target for your component(s)?**:

1. SharePoint Online only (latest)
2. SharePoint 2019 onwards, including SharePoint Online

**Update**:

I would recommend you to use the **Node.js v10.x** as below is given in [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment#install-nodejs):

> The current supported LTS version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is both **Node.js v8.x** and **Node.js v10.x**. Notice that 9.x or 11.x versions are currently not supported with SharePoint Framework development.

Comment: I tried selecting SharePoint Online only (latest) as well same behavior.

Comment: Which version of node and yeoman generator you are using?

Comment: node version : v13.1.0  YO version: 3.1.0

Comment: I would recommend you to use the **Node.js v10.x**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. If you change  `"isDomainIsolated": false,` to true it should fix it. It can be found in the .yo-rc.json file

Comment: it will be very beneficial if you mention where we can find this property "isDomainIsolated". Like some config file or where?

Comment: You can update your answer with information about the "isDomainIsolated" property.

Comment: Ah yep sorry it's in the .yo-rc.json file in the solution. You'll find this at the bottom of the file structure